# Sort mysql result by two column, but with a “holed” column

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have the following initial situation:

```sql
  +------------+-------------+
  | legacyRank | forcedRank  |
  +------------+-------------+
  | 0          | NULL        |
  | 1          | 6           |
  | 2          | NULL        |
  | 3          | 1           |
  | 4          | NULL        |
  | 5          | NULL        |
  | 6          | 2           |
  +------------+-------------+
```

You could generate this table by the following schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE two_column_order (
  legacyRank VARCHAR(45),
  forcedRank VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO two_column_order (legacyRank, forcedRank)
VALUES (5, NULL); 
INSERT INTO two_column_order (legacyRank, forcedRank)
VALUES (6, 2); 
INSERT INTO two_column_order (legacyRank, forcedRank)
VALUES (7, NULL); 
INSERT INTO two_column_order (legacyRank, forcedRank)
VALUES (0, NULL); 
INSERT INTO two_column_order (legacyRank, forcedRank)
VALUES (1, NULL); 
INSERT INTO two_column_order (legacyRank, forcedRank)
VALUES (2, 6); 
INSERT INTO two_column_order (legacyRank, forcedRank)
VALUES (3, NULL); 
INSERT INTO two_column_order (legacyRank, forcedRank)
VALUES (4, 1); 


SELECT * FROM two_column_order
order by
  CASE when `forcedRank`  <> NULL THEN `forcedRank`
  ELSE `legacyRank`
  END
```

The goal is to put each line with no-NULL `forcedRank` column in the accurate position mentioned in this `forcedRank` column. The expected rendering is like:

```sql
  +------------+-------------+
  | legacyRank | forcedRank  |
  +------------+-------------+
0 | 0          | NULL        |
1 | 3          | 1           |
2 | 6          | 2           |
3 | 2          | NULL        |
4 | 4          | NULL        |
5 | 5          | NULL        |
6 | 6          | 6           |
  +------------+-------------+
```

As you see, each line take the position ordered by the `forcedRank` column if not NULL. When the the NULL rows still sorted by the `legacyRank` column in the positions leaved unoccupied by the non-NULL rows, but never shift the forced rows.

In this order, I tried to use the `CASE WHEN` syntax inside the `ORDER BY` like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM two_column_order

order by 
  CASE WHEN (`forcedRank` is NULL )  THEN `legacyRank`
  END ,

  -`forcedRank` DESC,
  `legacyRank`
```

But the result doesn’t really feat my expectations:

```sql
+------------+-------------+
| legacyRank | forcedRank  |
+------------+-------------+
| 3          | 1           |
| 6          | 2           |
| 6          | 6           |
| 0          | NULL        |
| 2          | NULL        |
| 4          | NULL        |
| 5          | NULL        |
+------------+-------------+
```

So how can I make the `legacyRank` column get order beyond the forcedrank rows without shift them?

Comment: Do you actually expect a VARCHAR column to be sorted as numeric?

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` can't tbe comapred like that you need to use `IS`or in your case `IS NOT`

```
SELECT * FROM two_column_order
order by
  CASE when `forcedRank`  IS NOT NULL THEN `forcedRank`
  ELSE `legacyRank`
  END
```

| legacyRank | forcedRank |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | *null* |
| 1 | *null* |
| 4 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 3 | *null* |
| 5 | *null* |
| 2 | 6 |
| 7 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AxrTbXVq)

As the first answer won't give you the correct answer.

i have changed the order by adding a decimal point to the original number so that it will be bigger than the new forced rank.

it will keep the order and a the forced number is smaller then the legayrank, it get you follwoing result

```
SELECT * FROM two_column_order
order by
  CASE when `forcedRank`  IS NOT NULL THEN `forcedRank` 
  ELSE `legacyRank` + .1
  END
```

| legacyRank | forcedRank |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | *null* |
| 4 | 1 |
| 1 | *null* |
| 6 | 2 |
| 3 | *null* |
| 5 | *null* |
| 2 | 6 |
| 7 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9pbPv63y)

Comment: Ok. I alredy get this result, but as you see, the pined #1 take the position #2, the pined #2 take the position #3. Strangely, the pined #6 takes his real desired position. How to fix the problem with 1 and 2?

Comment: i could make it more compatible with your rquest see https://dbfiddle.uk/-ChLkF7A but you do eliminate `1 NULL` from the result

Comment: What a genius hack O.O If I understand correctly, you just add a decimal value. Then a non-forced row will be just after the previous forced row if any.

Comment: could you please make a new answear with the above trick, then I can mark it as resolved?

Comment: It does not work for this sample data: `(5, NULL), (6, 2), (7, NULL), (0, NULL), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, NULL), (4, 1)`: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qf610j07)

Comment: @forpas it looks ok to me, where does it not work?

Comment: (2, 4) is not at 4th (0 based)

Comment: @forpas the problem is already in the first sample data with the 1 and two, when you don't elimqante the single number that are bouled the rank will go down, but i made it clear from the beginning and the user hasn't a problem with that